# MySQL (PHPMyAdmin) REGEXP , difference between PHP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have regexp for finding external links on my website, it works fine in PHP:

`((http|https):\/\/(?!siteurl.com)[\w\.\/\-=?#]+)`

Now I want to use it in PHPMyAdmin in Search tab to search in whole database. It doesn't work. Are there any differences between PHP and MySQL REGEXP ? What should be changed in my regexp to make it work in PHPMyAdmin ?

Comment: mysql regex don't support backreference or lookahead

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Comment: So that might be hard to make this regexp work the same in MySQL... But is this possible ?

Comment: It is possible, but that will take some time to "unroll" the lookaround.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE url     REGEXP '^https?://'
  AND url NOT REGEXP '^https?://siteurl.com'
```

Why check for stuff after `//`?  If you do need to, be aware that MySQL does not handle `\w` or `\d`, so you need something like `[-[:alpha:]./=?#]+`.  `\w`, by itself, is `[[:alpha:]]`; `\d` is `[[:digit:]]`.  [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: When u use search in PHPmyAdmin (in whole DB) it's not possible to make WHERE / AND, there is only regular expression option so it has to be in one expression...

Comment: Wean yourself from the UI, and learn to use the mysql commandline tool.

Answer (score -1):

Use these patterns:

`\w`: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`\d`: `[0-9]`

Comment: I think you switched them around.